# To find duplicates in a python list, why doesn't this logic work?

Tags: python, list, duplicates

While I am aware that the best and simplest method to find duplicates in a list is by using Collections.Counter, I wish to know where does the following logic fail.

```
def uniquenumbercheck(listarg):
    for i in range(2,len(listarg)):
        for j in range(1,i-1):
            if(listarg[i]==listarg[j]):
                print("duplicate value appeared : "+str(listarg[i]))
                return
    print("all entered values are unique. ")
```

The program is running but failed to display the correct output.Could not figure out the mistake.For the example input of 1,1,0 integers to list, it says that they are unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Off-by-one** error. In Python, indexes start at `0`, not `1`. So,

```
for i in range(2, len(listarg)):
    for j in range(1, i - 1):
```

should be:

```
for i in range(1, len(listarg)):
    for j in range(0, i):
```

Also, `range(1, len(listarg))` can also be written as `range(len(listarg))`.

Answer (score 2):

i am assuming you are searching for duplicates within a list:

```
myl = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 1, 2]

for i in myl:
    if myl.count(i) > 1:
        print i
```

where the duplicates are printed out.

Comment: yes, there are ways, but trying to debug my logic.Ty anyhow.